# Heroku setup pip fail

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am trying to deploy a django application to Heroku, it dependes to django-admin-tools as you can see above in requirements.txt

When i run push command Heroku can't install the package, but I see it in pypi

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-admin-tools

Any help?

**requirements.txt**

```
MySQL-python==1.2.3
Django==1.6.2
simple-db-migrate==2.0.0
django-debug-toolbar==1.0.1
django-admin-tools==0.5.1
dj-database-url==0.2.2
dj-static==0.0.5
static==0.4
```

**push**

```
    git push heroku master







  Fetching repository, done.
    Counting objects: 8, done.
    Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
    Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
    Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 623 bytes, done.
    Total 6 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)

    -----> Python app detected
    -----> No runtime.txt provided; assuming python-2.7.6.
    -----> Using Python runtime (python-2.7.6)
    -----> Installing dependencies using Pip (1.5.4)
           Downloading/unpacking django-admin-tools==0.5.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
             http://bitbucket.org/izi/django-admin-tools/0.5.1 uses an insecure transport scheme (http). Consider using https if bitbucket.org has it available
             http://bitbucket.org/izi/django-admin-tools/ uses an insecure transport scheme (http). Consider using https if bitbucket.org has it available
         Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement django-admin-tools==0.5.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
       Cleaning up...
       No distributions at all found for django-admin-tools==0.5.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
       Storing debug log for failure in /app/.pip/pip.log

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app
```

if I run pip install django-admin-tools==0.5.1 in my machine it works, but it keep showing me error when I try to push to Heroku

Comment: What's the pip version in your computer?

Comment: Since pypa/pip#1423 it is no longer allowed to install packages that are not hosted on PyPI itself by default

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you are using a older version of pip in your local computer while Heroku is using newer version of pip.

django-admin-tools==0.5.1 is hosted on the bitbucket. While pip is no longer allowed to install packages that are not hosted on PyPI itself by default. So the installation failed.

Adding the following stuff to you requirements.txt would solve the problem.

```
--allow-unverified django-admin-tools
django-admin-tools==0.5.1
```

References:

[Forced use of --allow-external and --allow-unverified very inconvenient and not very intuitive #1423](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1423)

Comment: I tried this (but with PIL) and am still getting the error:

Some insecure and unverifiable files were ignored (use --allow-unverified PIL to allow).
       Cleaning up...
       No distributions at all found for PIL==1.1.7 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
       Storing debug log for failure in /app/.pip/pip.log

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app

What else can I do?

Comment: After half an hour of frantic search I finally found your answer - wish I could give you more than one upvote! (y)